# MySQL Connector net Why we need it?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mysql-connector

Hey can some1 explain me why we need to download MySQL connector net? im creating a website on visual studio 2010 and linking it with phpMyAdmin database.....but what does MySQL connector actually does?

thanks

Comment: First link in Google for [mysql connector net]: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net

Comment: Perhaps this will explain it:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-net.html

Answer (score 1):

PhpMyAdmin is a mysql database client made with php and connected to mysql database and hosted in Apache Server.Here we can execute mysql dml/ddl directly to view the immediate results.

MySql Connector Net is the library through which a Dot net Application will connect to mysql for further database communication.

Hope this will help you..

Comment: do we need Mysql connector tho? i mean is it necesary for the webpage to load up??

Comment: To retrieve the data from mysql database and show those in webpage as per requirement and to store the data as per user requirement, Dot Net developer must use the mysql connector net library in his/her application